# CRC: Does a little endian bytestream have a big endian CRC at the end?

Tags: crc

The algorithm to calculate a CRC involves dividing (mod 2) the data by a polynomial, and that, by nature starts at the biggest bit using the basic long division algorithm and works down (unless you're taking the shortcuts and using tables).

Now, the stream I'm dealing with has the requirements that the data is added little endian and the CRC remainder goes at the end, whereas if the CRC was applied and appended; the CRC remainder bits would appear at the leftmost point in the least significant bit given the bitstream is little endian.

So here's the question. We have a little endian stream with the CRC remainder at the "unexpected" end (correct me if I'm wrong please), should the CRC remainder be added big endian at the end of the bytestream, and then the CRC run on the whole bytestream (this is what I expect from the requirements) or something else?

How in industry is this normally done?

Major update for clarity thanks to Mark Adler's highly helpful answer.

[image]

I've read a few posts, but seen nothing where there seems to be a little endian bytestream with a CRC in the MSB (rightmost).

The image  above should describe what I'm doing. All the bytes are big endian bit order, but the issue is that the requirements state that the bytes should be little endian byte ordered, and then the CRC tacked on the end.

For the bytestream as a sequence of *bits* to be validated by the CRC remainder being placed at the *end*, the CRC remainder bytes should be added bit endian, therefore allowing the message as a whole to be validated with the polynomial. However this involves adding bytes to the stream in a mix of endiannesses, which sounds highly ugly and wrong.

Comment: Can you copy or point to these requirements?

Answer (score 3):

I will assume that by "biggest" bit, you mean most significant. First off, you can take either the most-significant bit or the least-significant bit of the first byte as the highest power of *x* for polynomial division. Both are in common use. There is no "by nature" here. And that has nothing to do with whether tables are used or not. Taking the least-significant bit as the highest power of *x*, the one you would call "not by nature" is in very common use, due to slightly faster and simpler software implementations as compared to using the most-significant bit.

Second, bit streams are neither "little endian", nor "big endian". Those terms are used for how *integers* are broken up into a sequence of *bytes*. That has nothing to do with the interpretation of a stream of bits as a polynomial. The terms you seem to be looking for are "reflected" and "not reflected" bit streams in and CRCs out. "reflected" means that the highest power of *x* is the least significant bit, and "not reflected" means it is the most significant bit.

If you look at [Greg Cook's catalogue of CRCs](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/all.htm), you will see as part of each definition `refin=false refout=false` or `refin=true refout=true`, meaning that the data coming in is reflected or not, and the CRC coming out is reflected or not, referring to where the highest power of *x* is found. For the CRC, the entire *n*-bits is reflected or not. In actual implementations, no bits are flipped for the input data or the output CRC. Instead, the constant CRC polynomial is reflected to match the data and CRC reflections. That is done once as the code is written, never during execution. (There is one outlier CRC in Greg's catalogue, `CRC-12/UMTS`, that has `refin=false refout=true`. For that one, the implementation would in fact have to reflect the CRC result every time.)

Given all that, I am left attempting to intepret your question. What do you mean by "the data is added little endian"? Does that mean the CRC is being calculated using the least-significant bit as the highest power of *x* (the opposite of your "by nature")? What does "the CRC remainder bits would appear at the leftmost point in the least significant bit given the bitstream is little endian" mean? That one is really confusing, since there is no leftmost point of a bit, and I can't tell at all what you're trying to say about the arrangement of the remainder bits.

The only thing I think I understand and can try to answer here is: "How in industry is this normally done?"

Well, as you can tell from the list of over a hundred CRCs, there is little normalcy established. What I can say is that CRCs have a special property that leads to a "natural" (now I can use that word) ordering of the CRC bits and bytes at the end of the stream of bits and bytes that the CRC was calculated on. That property is that if you append it properly, the CRC of the *entire* message, including the CRC at the end, will always be the same constant, if there are no errors in the message. *Now* little and big endian are useful terms, but *only* for the CRC itself, not the bit or byte stream. The proper order is little endian for reflected CRCs and big endian for non-reflected CRCs. (This assumes that the input and output have the same reflection, so this won't work for that one outlier CRC.)

Of course, I have seen many cases where a reflected CRC is used, but is appended to the stream big-endian, and vice versa, in which case this calculation of the CRC on the entire message doesn't work. That's ok, since the alternative way to check the CRC is to simply repeat what was done before transmission, which is to calculate the CRC only on the data portion of the message, then properly assemble the CRC from the bytes that follow it, and *compare* the two values. That is what would be done for any other hash that doesn't have that elegant mathematical property of CRCs.

Comment: One reason for using reflected in and reflected out is hardware that transmits data least significant bit first.  I'm not sure why a hardware implementation would choose to transmit least significant bit first.

Comment: Because that's what the hardware on the other end is expecting. All the way back to the RS-232 standard. Same for ethernet. And USB. All LSB first.

Comment: I'm aware of of the LSB first, but was wondering if there was a reason behind it. A hardware LFSR (linear feedback shift register) can shift either direction with the feedback, input and output pins swapped either way. It seems it's historical to a teletype, with some mods to signal levels to mod the interface to RS-232. A teletype is mostly mechanical, (cams, gears, mechanical hole sensors, mechanical hole punchers, ...), so the motor and the communication interface are the few electronic parts in a teletype.

Comment: Beats me. It goes all the way back to [Telex machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telex) sending 5-bit Baudot codes least-significant bit first.

Comment: Thanks @MarkAdler, that's a very helpful and kind answer. I've added some pictures for clarity.

Comment: Thank you the for the last paragraph.  I was looking for the effect of endianness on the residue.  I will transitively consider some protocols in-elegant.